# How to create a windows cmd shell with empty environment

Tags: windows, variables, cmd, environment-variables, env

I want to create a windows cmd with a empty environment, meaning no env variables. What would be the easiest way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `set` to list them all, split by the `=` sign, set them all to empty.

```
for /f "usebackq delims==" %f in (`set`) do (set %f=)
```